# WSL2 modprobe usbmon missing?

Tags: usb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, modprobe

According to [this page](https://www.xda-developers.com/wsl-connect-usb-devices-windows-11/), I should be able to use usbmon and other USB utilities in WSL2. I did everything exactly as lined out, the Windows part worked flawlessly (installing the USB passtrough drivers), as I attached an Arduino Uno USB serial port device to the WSL2, it does show up in the list. But `usbmon` module for some reason cannot be accessed as it is missing a required module. Running it as root also doesn't help. This is for school, I'm following school's manual. What am I doing wrong?

```
marpolda@DESKTOP-IQ3BUTG:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics CH340 serial converter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
marpolda@DESKTOP-IQ3BUTG:~$ modprobe usbmon
modprobe: FATAL: Module usbmon not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
marpolda@DESKTOP-IQ3BUTG:~$ sudo apt install usbmon
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package usbmon
```

This is the Linux kernel version I use inside WSL2:

```
marpolda@DESKTOP-IQ3BUTG:/boot$ uname -a
Linux DESKTOP-IQ3BUTG 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 02:56:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

USB attachment from Windows to WSL2 looks like this:

```
C:\Users\marpo>usbipd wsl list
BUSID  VID:PID    DEVICE                                                        STATE
1-1    1a86:7523  USB-SERIAL CH340 (COM3)                                       Not attached
1-3    1bcf:0005  Vstupní zařízení USB                                          Not attached
1-5    0408:a060  HD WebCam                                                     Not attached
1-14   8087:0aaa  Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R)                                Not attached


C:\Users\marpo>usbipd wsl attach --busid 1-1

C:\Users\marpo>usbipd wsl list
BUSID  VID:PID    DEVICE                                                        STATE
1-1    1a86:7523  USB-SERIAL CH340 (COM3)                                       Attached - WSL
1-3    1bcf:0005  Vstupní zařízení USB                                          Not attached
1-5    0408:a060  HD WebCam                                                     Not attached
1-14   8087:0aaa  Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R)                                Not attached
```

This is WSL version:

```
C:\Users\marpo>wsl --version
Verze WSL: 1.2.5.0
Verze jádra: 5.15.90.1
Verze WSLg: 1.0.51
Verze MSRDC: 1.2.3770
Verze Direct3D: 1.608.2-61064218
Verze DXCore: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Verze Windows: 10.0.25987.1000
```